# How to scrape lists into a list pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, loops, web-scraping

I want to scrape through the loop and output a list of lists but the error I keep getting is "list index is out of range" or "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

```
#BEGIN LOOP SCRAPE
studentIDs=[1,2,3]
for i, val in  enumerate(studentIDs):

    #Begin scraping
    out_data=[pd.read_html(browser.page_source)]
    #Clicking to another student webpage
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('returns to another page that needs to be scraped').click()
```

Comment: You need to include the line where the error exists. Seems we are seeing a portion of the code

Comment: when it loops, on the second go-around, it doesn't scrape and the error occurs. The error is "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: Yes and what line of code throws that error exactly? I assume it was the one from my first comment that you deleted

Comment: No, the error occurs on "out_data=[pd.read_html(browser.page_source)]" on the second loop-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
studentIDs=[1,2,3]
for index in range(len(studentIDs)):
 out_data=out_data+[pd.read_html(browser.page_source)]
```